# Sql Functions very slow

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

I am not expert in functions.  Inherited the following function which is very slow

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Diagnosed]
( @clientId As int)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @result  int;
Declare @return nvarchar(10);
set @result = (SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM  dbo.AdditionalInfo 
WHERE  dbo.AdditionalInfo.Type = 'Diagnosed' and  ClientId = @ClientId);
IF @result > 0
   set @return = 'Yes'
ELSE
   set @return = 'No';    
return @return;
END
```

Is this the right way to write a function?

Comment: Sql function is good, maybe you need some index on column "Type " and "ClientId"?

Comment: Thank you Antonio, here is the FOREIGN KEY
TABLE [dbo].[ClientAdditionalInfo]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ClientAdditionalInfo_Client] FOREIGN KEY([ClientId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Client] ([ClientID])

Comment: A function won't make a query run fast. If performance is slow, it means the query it contains itself is slow, or that the overall query is slow. Perhaps there are no indexes on `Type` or `ClientId`. Or perhaps the outer query is slow, or executes the function (and its query) once for each result row. Only table-value functions can be inlined. Scalar functions have to be executed once for each value

Comment: Using `COUNT` to check for existence is *definitely* slow because it has to find all matching rows. Checking for existence can be done easily with an `EXISTS` clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function looks fine. An index is not automatically created on a foreign key constraint. So, you should explicitly add an index, like this

```
CREATE INDEX ClientAdditionalInfo_ClientID
    ON [dbo].[ClientAdditionalInfo]
    (ClientID)
    INCLUDE ([Type])
```

Comment: This to be added to the ClientAdditionalInfo table?

Comment: It should be added to the table you are searching for. You mentioned two different names, one in the query and the other in the comment. I am not sure is this a mistake or you reference the same table.

Comment: Same table just my mistake!  Thank you it works great.